# Exposing properties to an implementation of IList

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with a piece of old code that I need to amend, I have added the Metadata property but cannot expose it, the code is simple.

```
public interface IBigThing : IList<ILittleThing>
{
    string Metadata { get; set; }
}   

[Serializable]
    public class BigThing: List<ILittleThing>, IBigThing , ISerializable
    {
        string m_Metadata;

        [DataMember]
        public string Metadata
        {
            get { return m_Metadata; }
            set { m_Metadata = value; }
        }

        #region Constructors
        public BigThing()
        { }

        public BigThing(string p_Metadata)
        {
            Metadata = p_Metadata;
        }
        #endregion



        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Metadata", Metadata);
        }
    }
```

When I inspect the app or serialize to json, the Metadata is ignored and can only be accessed if explicitly called.

```
IBigThing toReturn = new BigThingFactory.Manufacture();
string strJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(toReturn);
```

Im sure I am missing something simple, can anyone help please?

Comment: `BigThing` is not implementing `IBigThing`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Apologies Andrei, missed that.

Comment: What type are you serialising? Are you serialising `IList` or `IBigThing`?

Comment: @Gusdor I am trying to serialize IBigThing but it seems that the List is serialized and the Metadata is 'lost'.

Comment: Can you show us the code that performs the serialization?

Comment: thanks for help so far, I have added the (very primitive) serialization above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `[DataMember]` attribute to the property definition in `IBigThing`. The serialization framework only analyses the types that you tell it about and therefore will not see any declarations in `BigThing`.